# Flutter add padding to Textfield hinttext

Tags: flutter, dart

How do i add a padding to the textfield hint text so it has a gap between the icon box?

Currently it is like this:

[image]

Where the result that I am achieving for:
[image]

This is the code snippet:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 56.0),
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFE7ECEF), 
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
             topLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
             topRight: Radius.zero,
             bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
             bottomRight: Radius.zero,
          ),
          border: Border.all(
             color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
             width: 2.0,
          )
       ),
       child: Icon(MdiIcons.account, color: Colors.black),
    ),
    hintText: 'Username',
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
    borderSide: BorderSide(
       color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
       width: 2.0,
    ),
  ),
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
    borderSide: BorderSide(
       color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF), // Set your desired border color
       width: 2.0, // Set your desired border thickness
    ),
  ),
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
),),),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add `margin` in Container...

Here is the Updated Code

```dart
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Container(
/*---*/ margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right:15.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xFFE7ECEF),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
            topRight: Radius.zero,
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.zero,
          ),
          border: Border.all(
            color: const Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
            width: 2.0,
          ),
        ),
        child: const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.black),
      ),
      hintText: 'Username',
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
          width: 2.0,
        ),
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF), // Set your desired border color
          width: 2.0, // Set your desired border thickness
        ),
      ),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    ),
  ),
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the contentPadding property within the InputDecoration and set the vertical and horizontal values to control the padding around the hint text. Adjust these values according to your preferences to achieve the desired gap between the icon box and the hint text.

```
      // Add contentPadding to create a gap between the icon and hint text
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 15.0),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `contentPadding` property in `textfield` widget like this:

```
---contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by just using contentPadding, also refer material design for margin and padding sizes. [read here](https://m3.material.io/foundations/layout/understanding-layout/spacing) or [here](https://m2.material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html#spacing)

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0)
```